# SpriteKit: many assets with physicsBody on scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a 2D, orthogonal game that generates the map randomly. Many of tiles in the map are gatherable resources that the player character can interact with. In order to achieve this, a Agents/Components approach is used, giving these entities a physics body (with isDynamic set to false to avoid unnecessary calculations) in order to detect collisions (i.e. when the player reaches a resource and attempts to gather it). SpriteKit seems to quickly be unable to handle anything bigger a small 150x150 map memorywise, on the actual target device.

Is this approach fundamentally flawed? Is Unity a better choice in this case?

Comment: When you use 'view.showsFPS = true', 'view.showsNodeCount = true' and 'view.showsDrawCount = true', what values are you typically seeing?

Comment: 1 FPS and roughly 60k nodes. As soon as I removed the physical bodies the FPS count went back to a steady 60 FPS.

Comment: Have you defined collisionBitMask and contactTestBitMask for all the physicsbody's? If you don't define any, the default is checking all bodies against each other, which would be very costly. To turn off collision/contact detection for a node set both to 0. In your case, a resources collision/contactbitmask would just be the player, as that is the only node you want to test for.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to reply, John.

I did add both masks. Straight out of The demobots sample project. It creates a physics contact delegate in which you tell each entity which other entities should trigger notifications. 

I thought about another possibility: namely, not using physics at all. Create the random tilemap and store which coordinates have a relevant tile. Then when compare those with the player’s. Not sure how efficient it’s going to be and there will be many non player controlled entities (animals, enemies) that will spawn on the map.

Comment: That sounds reasonable if physics do not make sense in your game. You can use `sprite1.frame.intersects(sprite2.frame)` to check for overlap of one sprite with another, think of it like collision detection.

Comment: Sorry about the spelling of my earlier reply: had to edit it on mobile due to length and I made a mess. 

I will definitely try your suggestion! To be honest, this has made me wary of this game engine to the point I’m starting to look into Unity. There are many more entities and complex systems I still need to incorporate and the threat of poor performance will always loom in the horizon. I think I should cut my losses and use the proven solution. Thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

1. Create a pool for physics body of each type, like pool for trees physics bodies, stones and etc.
2. It will be empty for a moment, for each element in the array at the beginning of a game check for close objects to the player, iterating through 60k array will be faster, then background calculation of all physics moments and holding 60k physics bodies in memory. To check for the close objects there is no need for you to count correct distance(doing pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) is not an easy operation), it will be enough for you to mark object as close if abs(player.x - obj.x) < 100 && abs(player.y - obj.y) < 100 is true. This operation costs less, and it is still better.

2.1 If true. Then you take a physics body from the pool and assign it to  this node or create a new physics body of pool is empty.

2.2 If false. Then you save physics body of this node to the pool and remove it from the node

3. Its not a perfect solution, I'm not sure if it will give you a lot of profit, but it will decrease a number of physics body on a scene paying for such move with an iterating through a big array(that shall not take a lot of time), and making a basic operations like + and abs.
4. It's in your choice, when you should such checks, this can be by a Timer, or in update, or every time, you player moves on some constant distance(like every 100points), it can be an experimental part.